# Retrieving data from Firebase (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm kind of new to Firebase and learning it step by step(background is mongoDB and SQL). Right now I'm trying to retrieve data on the basis of id from the database. Now the problem is I can't find anything which will help me in retrieving the  data from the database.

the thing that I was able to find was this :

```
var ref = firebaseConnection.connect.ref(nodePath+ "/trip/id");
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log("INSIDE");
        var data = snapshot.val();
        console.log("data is : " + data);
});
```

My understanding is that this will work when a child is added so please help me out that is there any way like this `ref.find(id)` which would help me in finding something from the database or will I have to do something like `child_added` (like the code mentioned above) to get something from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it with a GET HTTP call to the address, adding ".json" to the end of the ref.

```
var path = nodePath + "/trip/" + id + ".json";
```

Comment: doesn't firebase provide something like something simple via which I can retrieve something from the database ?

Comment: a get http call is simple enough! 

There's 2 ways: 
- Using listeners, as you did in your example. That doesn't allow you to retrieve data unless something happens in the database (a child added, a child modified... etc)
- Using an HTTP GET to retrieve data

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but can you please post an example because the only way that I know how to make a HTTP GET call is through an ajax get but that would be async which I do not want and I'm not allowed to make a ajax call sync

Comment: it has to be async :(

Comment: and that would be through an ajax call ??

Comment: here's an example for nodejs : 
https://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request